# VS2019 Page not responding on open

Tags: asp.net

Converting from vs2008 to vs2019. I have a Page(s) that don't respond on open.

Here's the page-
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Product1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication4.Product1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

```
<asp:Label ID="LblTest" runat="server" Text="Test" style="font-weight: 700; color: #FF0000; font-size: xx-large"></asp:Label>
```

</asp:Content>

Code behind:

Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Public Class Product1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        'itemtotal = ShoppingCart.Instance.GetItemTotal()
        'Call the Main.master Master Page's DisplayDataFromPage method
        'Master.DisplayDataFromPage(itemtotal)
        LblTest.Visible = False
        Session("ID") = 3
        Response.Redirect("~/ProductList1.aspx")


    End If

    LblTest.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Neither the response redirect or .visible work

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Hum, that code does not make sense. On first page load, (non postback), then you do a re-direct to another page. In effect nothing can or ever will work since the page is redirected to another page. So I can't see how this page could have every worked, since the code setup to re-direct to another page. And when you do a re-direct to another page, then the code and render of the current page is stopped - tossed out, and will never be sent down to the client browser. Hence changes to visible for that label will never also be seen with that re-direct.  It not clear why the redirect does not work

Comment: When I first created the page, the response redirect didn't work so I added the label visible function and that didn't work. I commented out the post back "if" and that still doesn't  work.

Comment: Well, you have to test with the re-direct removed. Any update on that page will NEVER show if you execute a redirect, since now the code runs, redirects and starts display the new page - old page will never show any updates ever wtth a re-direct. So for testing, remove the redirect.  I would also test with code moved out of page load. Drop a button on the web page, double click on that button and in the code behind put in the visible = false. Get that working. Then try adding the re-direct to that button - get that working. Then you can start working on that code to change master page.

Comment: My fault, I not only commented out the post back "IF', But also the redirect and the visible False still doesn't work Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'If Not IsPostBack Then        'itemtotal = ShoppingCart.Instance.GetItemTotal()
        'Call the Main.master Master Page's DisplayDataFromPage method
        'Master.DisplayDataFromPage(itemtotal)
        'LblTest.Visible = False
        'Session("ID") = 3
        'Response.Redirect("~/ProductList1.aspx")
        ' End If
        LblTest.Visible = False
    End Sub

Comment: Like I said - take a step back. Drop a button on that page - get the visbile false working when you hit that button. Then consider introduction of the response redirect and see how that goes. Once you have the little bit of button code working, then you can then work on the next problem. If we can't get a simple button and the visible = false working, then trying all kinds of next things and code is out of the question here.

Comment: Took a step back and added a button to make visible=false. Still didn't work. Just a little fustrated.

Comment: So then start a new question Show the markup for the page and label. And show the code behind for that button that does not work for the label visible = false. Until you can get these kinds of things working, then a bunch of additional complex questions and code is out of the question.